# How to define Django view

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am trying to develop a chatbot using Django and depending on the user's input, various python scripts need to be run.

Having the project structure (presented below), is there a way to call the news.py in chatbot.js?

I have tried with an ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "news/",
  data: { }
}).done(function( o ) {
   print('success')
});
```

and defined *news/* in my *urls.py*

```
url('news/', getNews)
```

where *getNews* is defined in my views

```
from artemis.static.marketdata.news import scrape

class getNews():
    scrape()
```

but I get a *500 error* saying that *TypeError: object() takes no parameters*

Traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /news/
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
        response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

What would be the preferable approach in this case?
Any tip would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Which line raised the exception? what is scrape, function or object ?

Comment: @SamuelChen I have edited my answer to include the traceback, and scrape is a function in news.py

Comment: you may need to use function view "def" not "class"

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: yup, maybe "How to define Django view" is a better question title for this thread.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a substitute for reading the documentation

Comment: @KeykoYume how to write django views is extensively documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django has "function" view and "class" view.

You are defining `class getNews()`. So you have to choose use "function" view or "class" view.

To use function view, change "class" to "def":

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def getNews(request):
    result = scrape()
    return HttpResponse(result)
```

To use class view, define the "getNews()" in correct way.

in view:

```
from django.views import View
from django.http import HttpResponse

class NewsView(View):
   ...

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      result = scrape()
      return HttpResponse(result)
```

in urls.py:

```
from views import NewsView
...
url(r'^news/$', NewsView.as_view()),
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your class declaration is wrong.

```
class getNews(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # continue here

    def scrape(self):
        # continue here
```

New-style classes inherit from `object`, not from `NoneType`.

---

Note: this answer addresses a code error in the source, nothing to do with django, just python syntax.

Samuel Chen's answer addresses how you create a view in django. A django view is a new-style class, derived from `django.views.View`. It contains methods corresponding to the HTTP methods (i.e. `get`, `post`, `put` etc.).